How do I install VirtualBox extension pack on RHEL?
I successfully installed VirtualBox on my RedHat 8 install (version 7.0.7 - odd). However when I try to install "Extension Pack" - their versions are available for the even numbers (7.0.6 or 7.0.8).
I followed the procedure described in https://www.tecmint.com/install-virtualbox-rhel/.
Which version of "Extension Pack" I should get to install?
rpm -q VirtualBox; vboxmanage --version
package VirtualBox is not installed
7.0.14r161095

And this is what I get on the sudo dnf install VirtualBox-7.0:
Package VirtualBox-7.0-7.0.14_161095_el8-1.x86_64 is already installed.


If you followed that linked tutorial, you should have ended up with the package VirtualBox-7.0-7.0.8_156879_el8-1.x86_64.rpm which should be VirtualBox version 7.0.8_156879.  Post the output of rpm -q VirtualBox; vboxmanage --version if you think you have a different version installed.

@GracefulRestart, OP updated with the results of the command.

You've installed version 7.0.14, not 7.0.7. Its extpack is here: https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/7.0.14/
